# Regex to match a string within a url

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics

I need to pull out links with a certain set of numbers and a string in their URL in Google Analytics, so I'm setting up a filter.

This is my input url: http://website.com/content/123/12/1234?utm_source=ABC&utm_campaign=ThisIsWhatINeed

In this link, I need the regex to match /content/123/12/1234 (or any numbers in the xxx/xx/xxxx format) and also to match the exact string ThisIsWhatINeed

I have the regex `\/content\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+` to match the number part `/content/123/12/1234`, and this works fine. But I can't figure out how to also match the `ThisIsWhatINeed`. I've tried `\/content\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+ThisIsWhatINeed` but some vital part is missing.

I've been using a regex tester and it says that everything matches, but then at the end I get the message 'Global pattern flags g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)'

I will confess I'm very new to regex and am just learning what all the tokens mean.

PS - I know I can pull out campaigns by other means in GA - I have a specific reason for needing to set up this filter

Comment: Do not blindly test on the regex tester sites. In GA (RE2) regex, you do not need to escape `/`, e.g. You also might just need capturing groups. Try [`(/content/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+).*utm_campaign=([^&]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Pcm0jy/2) in GA.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match the whole string:

To match the `/123/12/1234` part you can use a character class.
To match a more generic link, you could exchange `http://website.com/` to just `.*?`
To match your string after the campaign attribute, you can use a negated character class, marked bei `^` in the character class. This means, the pattern matches every character, as long as it's not a `&` sign.

```
http://website.com/content/[\d/]+.*?utm_campaign=[^&]*?
```

To explain the global modifier:
Usually your attempt to match something with regex would return on the first match. So if you're trying to match multiple links, the first match would return and stop your request.
When global flag is set, the pattern will match as often as possible and returns, when there is no match left.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answers and you both being kind to an ignorant newbie! 

Both responses have given .*utm_campaign=([^&]* to match the campaign part of the link, but it's a specific campaign I need to match, not any link with a campaign tag. 

I've edited it to (\/content\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+.*bananas), which seems to be working in the regex tester but not in GA. GA wouldn't accept anything else, or when I tried to take the escapes out (I probably just deleted them incorrectly).